# How to relax a requirement in a method

Tags: multiple-dispatch

What does it mean to relax a requirement? For example in a simple method which takes in two Integers and adds them together to another Integer, how can one relax a requirement in that method?

```
package client
import even.Even
import natural.Natural
    void f(Integer x,Integer y) {
         Integer z = add(x,y);
}
```

Both Even and Natural extends class Integer, if that's relevant. All three classes have different add() methods, Integer is the only class which has it on the form of the method f() in client.

Comment: I assume you mean making the method signature more "generic". E.g. you have an interface specifying an ``Integer`` as parameter type, but you can "loosen" the definition in your implementation, so that it takes a more general ``Number``.

Comment: @qqilihq yes, I believe that this is the requirement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Where can i change to Number?

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough - I wrote about it in my last *[post](http://alfasin.com/inheritance-overflow/)*:
 
“Multiple dispatch” behavior can be achieved in “single dispatch” Languages by using the *[Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)* (described originally in “design patterns” book).

Checkout the Java code example from the link above:

```
interface CarElementVisitor {
    void visit(Wheel wheel);
    void visit(Engine engine);
    void visit(Body body);
    void visit(Car car);
}

interface CarElement {
    void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor); // CarElements have to provide accept().
}

class Wheel implements CarElement {
    private String name;

    public Wheel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor) {
        /*
         * accept(CarElementVisitor) in Wheel implements
         * accept(CarElementVisitor) in CarElement, so the call
         * to accept is bound at run time. This can be considered
         * the first dispatch. However, the decision to call
         * visit(Wheel) (as opposed to visit(Engine) etc.) can be
         * made during compile time since 'this' is known at compile
         * time to be a Wheel. Moreover, each implementation of
         * CarElementVisitor implements the visit(Wheel), which is
         * another decision that is made at run time. This can be
         * considered the second dispatch.
         */ 
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class Engine implements CarElement {
    public void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class Body implements CarElement {
    public void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class Car implements CarElement {
    CarElement[] elements;

    public Car() {
        //create new Array of elements
        this.elements = new CarElement[] { new Wheel("front left"), 
            new Wheel("front right"), new Wheel("back left") , 
            new Wheel("back right"), new Body(), new Engine() };
    }

    public void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor) {     
        for(CarElement elem : elements) {
            elem.accept(visitor);
        }
        visitor.visit(this);    
    }
}

class CarElementPrintVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
    public void visit(Wheel wheel) {      
        System.out.println("Visiting " + wheel.getName() + " wheel");
    }

    public void visit(Engine engine) {
        System.out.println("Visiting engine");
    }

    public void visit(Body body) {
        System.out.println("Visiting body");
    }

    public void visit(Car car) {      
        System.out.println("Visiting car");
    }
}

class CarElementDoVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
    public void visit(Wheel wheel) {
        System.out.println("Kicking my " + wheel.getName() + " wheel");
    }

    public void visit(Engine engine) {
        System.out.println("Starting my engine");
    }

    public void visit(Body body) {
        System.out.println("Moving my body");
    }

    public void visit(Car car) {
        System.out.println("Starting my car");
    }
}

public class VisitorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarElement car = new Car();
        car.accept(new CarElementPrintVisitor());
        car.accept(new CarElementDoVisitor());
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that since it's using symmetric multiple dispatch, it doesn't find one single method that's the best fit. SInce it has not implemented integer.Integer which has the add method on the right form. Would it be a relaxation to either make either Integer x,y or z to type Even or Natural?

Comment: @user2900132 Relaxation: Even -> Integer. Not relaxation (that's actually a restriction): Integer -> Even.

Comment: ok. this is an exercise, where they're asking me which requirement i could relax to make the call f(..) valid.

Comment: If I understood you correctly then yes, you *can* relax even/odd to be Integer (if they extend it).